# Pronunciation of 'Teixcalaan'

Tags: languages, pronunciation, teixcalaan

I was wondering what the correct pronunciation of the word 'Teixcalaan' (in Teixcalaanli) is. I rewrote the word using the IPA and arrived at (except using the sound 'l' for the letter 'l' instead of 'ɣ' which the book suggests -- a typo?):

```
tʰeɪkskɑːlɑn
```

[pronunciation](http://ipa-reader.xyz/?text=t%CA%B0e%C9%AAksk%C9%91%CB%90l%C9%91n&voice=Joey)

But in the audiobooks it sounds different, namely the second 'a' has a longer sound rather than the first. I know it sounds counterintuitive but based on the IPA equivalents mentioned at the end of the book, in Teixcalaanli, 'a' is the longer version of the ɑ sound and 'aa' is the short one. So what am I missing here?

Comment: Thanks for asking the question, I just started reading this :)

Comment: Can you clarify what IPA you've seen? Does the book say /tʰeɪkskɑːɣɑn/?

Comment: @Jetpack It does not say that. There's no pronunciation guide for whole words in the book just for individual letters, for the letter 'l' it says the following:
l—ɣ—bell, ball

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is what the author [says](https://twitter.com/ArkadyMartine/status/1097587568122740736):

> Teyks-kah-lan. First vowel is the sound in 'hey', second vowel is the
> 'a' in 'father', third vowel is the 'a' in 'sample'.

This is not as precise as rendering it in IPA, but hopefully it helps. The "a in father" is (typically) a long vowel *[ɑː]* whereas the "a in sample" is short *[æ]*, which seems consistent with the Teixcalaanli rule of "a" being the long vowel and "aa" the short one.

Comment: Thank you, this clears it up. Also the pronunciation in the audiobook is hence wrong [(excerpt from audiobook)](https://youtu.be/o_fw-vPnxjg?t=10). This also suggests that the word 'ixplanatl' has a somewhat unnatural (at least to my ears) pronunciation with two consequent long a's, right?

Comment: I guess so. I don't have the physical book to hand, but it had a glossary at the end which gave the pronunciation of many of the Teixcalaanli words. Surely iplanati was in it.

Comment: As a great example of why the IPA is needed for things like this, I use the same vowel sound for "father" and "sample", so that tweet wouldn't have helped at all!